# When pressing key in keyboard, Is the signal sent to CPU binary?

Tags: keyboard

"*When we press a key on the keyboard, it pushes down the dome shaped rubber button which in turn electrically connects the top & bottom layer at that point and the signal is sent to the COB IC. The IC processes the **signal** and sends it to the computer through a PS2 port or USB.*" -[EngineeringGarage](https://www.engineersgarage.com/insight/how-computer-keyboard-works) (ctrl + f to find it)

Is the **signal** sent to CPU binary? (e.g. letter "a" = 00000001) ?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Everything sent to the CPU is binary. It is also hexadecimal, decimal and octal too. Binary is just the easiest representation to "work" with operations within the CPU and integrated circuits. The bits may be side-by-side as in a parallel bus or taken in one at a time (serial) but when taken as a group the data they represent can be shown in any way you like. The CPU uses binary representations, arithmetic and logic, but the actual data it works on will either be a group of bits that when looked at one way is "just" a series of 1's and 0's and another way it is the letter "a".

If you look at any given data line on the CPU at a given moment then it will either be a 1 or a 0 but in order to have any useful information you need either a group or series of bits that makes up a byte or series of bytes.

When you press a key then as you say the signal is sent through various integrated circuits until a signal at the CPU effectively says `a key was pressed, can you run some code to find out what?` at which point the processor will inform the operating system which in turn will find the driver responsible for reading the keyboard device which in turn will go away and will (through the processor and other ICs) query the device asking what keycode was pressed.

As far as what is returned as a "keypress" is concerned it is nothing more than data. It is simultaneously hexadecimal, decimal, binary and "the character A".

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer is **yes**, but of course a more in-depth answer just couldn't be as easy as "yes", could it!

First, there is not usually (except on n-key-rollover keyboards) a direct correlation between pressing a key and a single "signal". Normally, there's at least *two* signals. For cost reasons, the majority of keyboards is built with some kind of (implementation dependent) matrix of wires where pressing any one key results in two signals, and the IC then decodes that in some particular way. Usually, keyboards are made such that keys which are commonly held down together (or timely close to each other) have a different enough wiring so the IC can indeed figure it out correctly, for normal use.
Keyboards where every key is individually wired exist, but are the exception, not the norm.

Now, the information ("signal") that one or several keys are down is encoded in a couple of numbers on the keyboard's IC. Which is, of course, a binary number (it couldn't be anything different!). And... *nothing is being sent!* Wait what? Yes, that's right.

Every now and then, the USB Master (a controller IC in your computer, usually on the mainboard) asks the Slave (the USB controller in your keyboard) whether there's something to tell. The USB standard specifies that the Slave may only send when requested ("polled") by the Master. Keyboards normally run in interrupt transfer mode, so the keyboard gets a chance to tell the computer how often it would ideally like to be asked for updates (but it is still required to only answer to requests, not act upon itself), and the size of the answer frames is somewhat limited (64 bytes on USB2, for a couple of keys that's normally way enough).
Typically, on USB2 keyboards, the best poll interval you can get is 1ms, but USB3 would allow for 0.125ms<sup>[1]</sup>.

The controller in your keyboard now encapsulates the number (or several of them) in a limited-size packet of a particular well-known format which includes an identifier, a checksum (CRC) as well as some other information, and puts all that "on the wire" bit by bit.
This transfer is *strictly* binary, of course, as there is only one data cable (...for each direction) which can *either* have Voltage or, well, not. But the signal doesn't look anything like the original signal any more, and it only makes sense to look at a complete packet, not a single bit.

The keyboard will send, and retransmit up to three times if the computer detects a CRC error, so the transmission also is not just fire-and-forget, but a *somewhat* more complicated [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_(Communications)#PROTOCOL).

Once something was received and the CRC was good, the controller generates an interrupt, and the device driver does *something* to extract the scan code from the received message. This is then passed through some more or less elaborate filter and analysis mechanisms within the operating system (possibly maintaining a set of "currently pressed keys" and possibly calling hooks, and whatever) until finally *something* (depends on operating system) lands in the message queue of the program which has "the focus" (where it is usually translated to a character). This *something* is usually a notification of the "key down" kind, paired with corresponding "key up" messages, and possibly "repeat" messages being generated by the operating system according to some timer.
The "signal" is, of course, still binary, since that's the only thing the CPU understands. But it looks, again, quite different now. And sure enough, it's much more complicated than just a simple little number sent over a wire.

When the key message gets translated to characters, several keypresses may further be combined into a single character (or the other way around, or some variable-length encoding, or other funny things).
Again, the "signal" is still necessarily binary, but -- again -- it will look much different than previously.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> This may be interesting for super-super-hardcore gamers who worry about every millisecond of lag. Polling *at most* once per millisecond on a USB2 keyboard means an added average latency of 0.5ms (irrespective of any time it may take to process the keypress otherwise or send out a network packet). On an old USB keyboard, which is "just the same" superficially, the lowest possible poll interval is 10ms!

Comment: The long and short answers are actually *no*, and you yourself explained why: there's no signal sent to the cpu from the keyboard.